# How to call a JS method when user clicks at dynamically created link. JQuery, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I dynamically create a link at view to call a method of controller:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var data="SomeDataToController";
     var link=document.createElement('a');
     var linkText=document.createTextNode("Delete");
     link.appendChild(linkText);
     link.title="Title text";
     link.href=HelloWorld(ee); 
    document.getElementById("imageBox1").
    appendChild(link);


    }
   function HelloWorld(data){
    alert(data);}
```

How to call method HelloWorld(data) just if an user clicks on link "Delete"?

I've tried to invoke code at "onclick" event, but HelloWorld() function calls immediately when  tag is built. However, I would like to call when an user clicks at the link.

Comment: $(link).click(HelloWorld) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to attach a event. You need to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` instead of directly assign function to `href`.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  link.addEventListener('click', HelloWorld(ee), false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  link.attachEvent('onclick', HelloWorld(ee));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also call HelloWorld immediately and set its return value as the function handler, rather than the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.on` command of jQuery, but use it as a delegate. That's to handle creation of objects also after your page is loaded.

For example you can attach the `.on` at the `<body>` level and say that, everytime an `<a>` with class "clickme" is clicked, it will execute your method.

Something like this:

```
$(body).on("click", ".clickMe", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  HelloWorld('my value taken from data- attribute or whatever');
});
```

Comment: Implemented a sample. Written without testing it, but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems here: you shouldn't try to set an onclick handler by setting href to something and you're actually calling the `HelloWorld()` function when assigning, so basically you're assigning whatever that function returns into the href.

You should rather use `addEventListener` to attach a function that calls `HelloWorld()` on click:

```
link.addEventListener('click', function() { HelloWorld(data); })
```

If you need to support Internet Explorer before version 9, you also need to have conditional for that and use `attachEvent()` rather.

Answer (score 1):

If you  want to execute the JavaScript function when user click on your elements,you can use something like this.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = "SomeDataToController";
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode("Delete");
        link.appendChild(linkText);
        link.title = "Delete";
        link.onclick = eval(getDeleted);
        document.getElementById("imageBox1").appendChild(link);

    });

    function getDeleted() {

        var f = "delete";
        Delete(f);
    }

    function Delete(f) {
        alert(f);
    }
```

But I would like to use jQuery functionality something like this.

`

```
function myHandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.foo);
}
$('#imageBox1 a').on("click", {
    foo: "bar"
}, myHandler);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to add a click handler to all a tags in the document

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that use jQuery to create dynamic HTML.

```
$("#imageBox1").append('<a href="' + javascript:alert(1); + '">' + text + '</a>');
```